# Nested generic type interface

Tags: java, android, generics

I am trying to create an interface that some of my classes will implement. While this works fine for one Type T:

```
public interface AsyncResponse<T> {
    void processFinish(T output);
}
```

This allows the use of `processFinish<String>` etc.

Making this work for generic lists doesn't seem to. Or atleast, I can't grasp how to be able to allow one of and not limited to the following:

1. LinkedHashSet output.
2. ArrayList output.

I tried the following but that didn't work:

```
public interface AsyncGenericResponse<T<X>>{
    void processFinish(T<X> output);
}
```

and

```
public interface AsyncGenericResponse<LinkedHashSet<T>{
    void processFinish(LinkedHashSet<T> output);
}
```

Neither of the solutions seemed to work. How can I solve this and is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generic type is only `T`, the method accepts a `LinkedHashSet<T>`, but there is no "nested generic" in the class declaration here.

The following code will compile just fine:

```
public interface AsyncGenericResponse<T>{
    void processFinish(LinkedHashSet<T> output);
}
```

Comment: Also, consider using a `Collection<T>` super-type instead of a specific `Set` or `List` if you just need a collection, but don't want to specify the exact type at parameter-level yet.

Comment: @Matthijs But in this case while it will work for your `List` types but it will no longer work for types, for example, `String`?

Comment: But there is no option to make both the in this case LinkedHashSet as the generic type it uses variable? As in my interface using <T<X>> ?

Comment: @Unheilig that is correct in this case indeed. I can however remove the LinkedHashSet and only keep the T. This allows me to set the type upon implementing the interface. It is not ideal but if <T<X>> isn't possible, it'll have to do.

Comment: @Matthijs I wonder if it could be even more generic so that it would work for both cases. But thanks for answering.

Comment: @Unheilig I really hoped for the more generic answer indeed, but there doesn't seem to be such a possibility in Java.